# RSpec capybara with Chromium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, chromium

I'm trying to configure RSpec suite to run against `Chromium` browser (instead of `google-chrome`)...
The test suite fails with the following error

```
     1.2) Failure/Error: Unable to infer file and line number from backtrace

          Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
            session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
          # 0   chromedriver                        0x0000000103190329 chromedriver + 3838761
          # 1   chromedriver                        0x000000010312a123 chromedriver + 3420451
          # yada yada
```

I've installed `ChromeDriver` and chromium browser (via `brew cask install chromedriver chromium`)...

here is the `spec_helper.rb` configurations for capybara

```
require "capybara/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"
require "selenium/webdriver"

# Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

This works perfectly when chrome is installed (same `v.82` as chromium) but doesn't work with chromium... is there any way to get the selenium chrome driver to work with chromium?

Comment: on a side note, the selenium chrome driver correctly identifies chromium (binary) and spawns it (I guess correctly for testing -with the 'this tab is automated' banner) but for a fraction of a second before the test fails with the mentioned error

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```rb
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chromium do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(binary: "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium")
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chromium
Capybara.app_host = 'https://example.org'
visit('/')
```

As you discovered, the Chrome/Chromium version needs to match the ChromeDriver version. This means that `brew cask install chromium` will probably not work because it will install the latest nightly build.

To get a working Chromium build, first check your ChromeDriver version:

```
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776})
```

Next, you need to find a stable Chromium build with the same major version. I'd suggest grabbing a build from https://chromium.woolyss.com/ -- it will have a tag like:

> 81.0.4044.129 (737173) • Tuesday, 28 Apr 2020

If you know the build number (737173 in this example), you can also download a compatible snapshot from the Chromium build repository:

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/737173/chrome-mac.zip

Comment: `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(binary: "/usr/bin/chromium")` did it for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found to get RSpec + Capybara working on Alpine Docker image:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:3.0.2-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache chromium chromium-chromedriver
```

`Gemfile`

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara' # 3.36.0 as of writing this
  gem 'selenium-webdriver' # 4.0.3 as of writing this
  # Make sure no other gems are installed, such as `webdrivers`
end
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chromium do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,900")
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, capabilities: options)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chromium
```